# Why does it appear that Brave is remembering my gmail session in a new private window?

Tags: windows, brave

I'm using the Brave browser (Version 1.49.132 Chromium: 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit)), and I expect that when I close a private window, all session data will be forgotten.

But what I see is:

- open private window
- log in to gmail account
- close private window
- open a new private window
- go to gmail.com, and the same account is already logged in

Chrome does not do this.

How do I get Brave to discard my data when I close a private window?

Comment: No repro with Version 1.49.128 Chromium: 111.0.5563.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Debian 11

Comment: No repro with Version 1.49.132 Chromium: 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Debian 11

Comment: Did you close *all* private windows?

Comment: @DanielB No, I didn't, thank you. Maybe browsers should warn you if you have other private windows open, if only to save the world from silly questions!

Answer (score 2):

Brave only forgets the private information when *all* private windows are closed. Closing one of them, even when that window was the window you logged in on, is not enough.

To avoid making this mistake, you need to look at the number next to the sunglasses icon in your private window. It tells you how many private windows are open at this point. So if this says 2 before you close a window, you need to go and find the other private window and close that too if you expect your data to be removed!

So the actual repro is:

- open a private window and forget about it.
- open another private window
- log in to gmail account
- close the newest private window, but not the original one, because you ignored the helpful `2` hint.
- open a new private window
- go to gmail.com, and the same account is already logged in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).